# Smoothing of histogram with a low-pass filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, histogram, gaussian, smoothing

I have an image and my aim is to binarize the image. I have filtered the image with a low pass Gaussian filter and have computed the intensity histogram of the image.

I now want to perform smoothing of the histogram so that I can obtain the threshold for binarization. I used a low pass filter but it did not work. This is the filter I used.

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', [8 8],2);
```

Can anyone help me with this? What is the process with respect to smoothing of a histogram?

```
imhist(Ig);
```

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: Can you post an image of the thing you're trying to filter?

Comment: Can you at least tell us how many bins your histogram has?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a very similar problem recently, trying to compute a threshold in order to exclude noisy background pixels from MRI data prior to performing other computations on the images.  What I did was fit a spline to the histogram to smooth it while maintaining an accurate fit of the shape.  I used the [splinefit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13812-splinefit) package from the file exchange to perform the fitting.  I computed a histogram for a stack of images treated together, but it should work similarly for an individual image.  I also happened to use a logarithmic transformation of my histogram data, but that may or may not be a useful step for your application.

```
[my_histogram, xvals] = hist(reshape(image_volume), 1, []), number_of_bins);
my_log_hist = log(my_histogram);
my_log_hist(~isfinite(my_log_hist)) = 0;   % Get rid of NaN values that arise from empty bins (log of zero = NaN)
figure(1), plot(xvals, my_log_hist, 'b');
hold on
breaks = linspace(0, max_pixel_intensity, numberofbreaks);
xx = linspace(0, max_pixel_intensity, max_pixel_intensity+1);
pp = splinefit(xvals, my_log_hist, breaks, 'r');
plot(xx, ppval(pp, xx), 'r');
```

Note that the spline is differentiable and you can use ppdiff to get the derivative, which is useful for finding maxima and minima to help pick an appropriate threshold.  The `numberofbreaks` is set to a relatively low number so that the spline will smooth the histogram.  I used linspace in the example to pick the breaks, but if you know that some portion of the histogram exhibits much greater curvature than elsewhere, you'd want to have more breaks in that region and less elsewhere in order to accurately capture the shape of the histogram.

Comment: Although fitting a spline to a histogram would work, the parameters would likely have to be adjusted based on the shape of the histogram. Otherwise, important details such as peaks or valleys might be totally  lost. This could be the equivalent of using a very large filter which in some cases might be what you want. But the variability between images might be so high that if human intervention is required to select the parameters then you mine as well just plot the histogram and manually select a threshold.

Comment: Hey Matt.. Thanks for your in-dept response. I will try the spline method and see if it works.

Comment: cwadding, the only human-adjustable parameters here are the number and distribution of the breaks.  If you don't have good a priori information about the histogram, then you'd simply need to have more breaks and have them evenly distributed across the range of pixel intensity values for your application.  There's not really any reason for human intervention at run-time.  The spline is being fit to the data in a least squares sense, so the parameters related to control point locations and knot vectors are adjusted automatically to achieve the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

To smooth the histogram you need to use a 1-D filter. This is easily done using the [filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html) function. Here is an example:

```
I = imread('pout.tif');
h = imhist(I);
smooth_h = filter(normpdf(-4:4, 0,1),1,h);
```

Of course you can use any smoothing function you choose. The mean would simply be `ones(1,8)`.

Since your goal here is just to find the threshold to binarize an image you could just use the [graythresh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/graythresh.html) function which uses Otsu's method.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is a nice simple approach.